# How do I find out what version of SMB is in use by each attached client to a Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016, server-message-block, cifs

I am trying to determine which version of SMB/CIFS is in use by clients attached to shared folders on my Windows Server 2016.  If I run the powershell command `Get-SmbConnection` on the Windows Server, it will show the SMB version in use on shared folders that the server has connected to, not the SMB versions of clients connected to it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I did find a way to do this.  Hopefully this helps someone else looking for the same information.

On the server, open a powershell then enter this command:
`Get-SmbSession | Select-Object -Property ClientComputerName,ClientUserName,Dialect`

For more verbose output:
`Get-SmbSession | Select-Object -Property *`